# Leafletjs Leaflet get marker out of group

Tags: get, leaflet, openstreetmap, marker

I am creating a map using OpenStreetMaps and Leafletjs.
All my markers are pushed in separate groups. Now i want to access a single marker in a group for using a "dragend" method and getting the Position of the marker.

I have already tried to get to the marker by iterating the Group. But by iterating, I get layers returned. I can't get the Coordinates of the Marker on the layer.

Is there any other way of accessing these markers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to look for your marker.

The event dragend gives you a pointer to it.

So you could do something like this (code may require some tweaks).

```
function OnDragEnd(event){
    var lng = event.target.getLatLng().properties.lng
    //TO DO
  }
```

and you can pass as callback OnDragEnd when you create your event on the marker.

Edit:

You have to bind the event like this:

```
YourMarker.on("dragend",OnDragEnd);
```

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your answer! But sadly, that idea didn´t work for me. The function doesn´t react to any dragging.

Comment: Sure. You have to bind the event to.

Comment: You edited "YourMarker.on("dragend",OnDragEnd);". But thats exactly where my problem is. I have to access the marker, which is in a Group. But i cant...

Comment: You have to bind the event at the creation of your marker, before you add it to the map.